# Issue with FindCurvePath

Tags: bugs, mathematical-optimization, version-9, version-8

I have a problem with the function `FindCurvePath`. In some cases it crashes the *Mathematica* 9 Kernel. Here an example, where it crashes the kernel:

```
data = {{368, 195}, {368, 196}, {368, 197}, {368, 198}, {368, 201}, {368,
 202}, {368, 206}, {368, 208}, {368, 209}, {368, 215}, {368, 
244}, {368, 252}, {368, 253}, {368, 254}, {368, 255}, {368, 
257}, {368, 268}, {368, 273}, {368, 277}, {368, 297}, {368, 
300}, {368, 311}, {368, 323}, {368, 325}, {368, 327}, {368, 
332}, {368, 333}, {368, 334}, {368, 335}, {368, 339}, {368, 
342}, {368, 345}, {368, 348}, {368, 357}, {368, 376}, {368, 
390}, {368, 395}, {368, 405}, {368, 414}, {368, 447}, {368, 
450}, {368, 453}, {368, 500}, {368, 522}, {368, 530}, {368, 
538}, {368, 554}, {368, 558}, {368, 560}, {368, 570}, {368, 
580}, {368, 585}, {368, 602}, {368, 604}, {368, 618}, {368, 
619}, {368, 620}, {368, 621}, {368, 622}, {368, 624}, {368, 
632}, {368, 677}, {368, 719}, {368, 724}, {368, 753}, {368, 
756}, {368, 759}, {368, 764}, {368, 824}, {368, 832}, {368, 
835}, {368, 847}, {368, 856}, {368, 879}, {368, 882}, {368, 
896}, {368, 906}, {368, 918}, {368, 944}, {368, 954}, {368, 
958}, {368, 975}, {369, 7}, {369, 13}, {369, 37}, {369, 38}, {369,
 49}, {369, 50}, {369, 57}, {369, 69}, {369, 71}, {369, 74}, {369,
 84}, {369, 89}, {369, 92}, {369, 93}, {369, 97}, {369, 99}, {369,
 105}, {369, 106}};

FindCurvePath[data];
```

If I change, e.g. the last number in "working" from 106 to 105 it works fine!

```
data // ReplacePart[#, {-1, 2} -> 105] & // FindCurvePath
```

Does anybody know a solution to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Please do not tag with bugs unless a bug is confirmed. That being said, I can confirm the crash on 9.01 Windows 7 64bit. Your data does of course not really lend itself to form a "smooth" curve, but the kernel *ought* to survive that.

Comment: Some more details on the crash (again win7 9.0.1 64bit)... Application Name: MathKernel.exe
  Application Version: 9.0.61.57492
  Application Timestamp: 51021c01
  Fault Module Name: mkl_avx.dll
  Fault Module Version: 10.3.5.1
  Fault Module Timestamp: 4e26d970
  Exception Code: c00000fd
  Exception Offset: 000000000020c0c5
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID: 2057
  Additional Information 1: 52ed
  Additional Information 2: 52ed464030635dad555265b4eebdbad3
  Additional Information 3: 60e6
  Additional Information 4: 60e65a47bc25935a512d864e957381d4

Comment: I can run both of your examples without a crash of my Mathematica 9.0.1 kernel on a Win (32-bit) platform. For me `FindCurvePath[crashing]` in your example returns the list: `{ {2, 1, 100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, 83}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82} }`

Comment: I can reproduce this v9.0.1.0 on OSX 10.8.5. Kernel CPU demand spikes and after a couple of seconds the kernel crashes. I'd report this to Wolfram research if I were you. Can you include your version of mathematica and OS in the question as well?

Comment: I wrote an Email to the MM support. If I ll get an answer, I ll let you know. So far, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Bimmel, any news about or from MMA Support?

Comment: No crash with version 11.2.0 on Windows 7 x64.